# I get a runtime error on a coding site's (codechef) online compiler

Tags: java, runtime

I get a runtime error on a coding site's (codechef) online compiler. I have seen through all the array out of bounds conditions. You can find the problem [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/K1).

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighwayFactory {

    int[] Warehousesx = new int[5000];
    int[] Warehousesy = new int[5000];
    int[] Pointsx = new int[5000];
    int[] Pointsy = new int[5000];
    double[] minDist = new double[5000];
    double[] sumDistArr = new double[5000];
    int a, b, c, nWare;
    int tCases;
    int minX, maxX = Warehousesx[0];
    float x1, y1, x2, y2;
    double[] distance = new double[5000];
    double min = 0;

    void gett() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("enter no of test cases");
        tCases = in .nextInt();
    }

    void start() {
        gett();
        for (int i = 1; i <= tCases; i++) {
            getValues();
            calcMinMax();
            pointscalc();
            distanceCalc();
        }
    }

    void getValues() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.println("enter value of n");
        nWare = in .nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter a,b,c");
        a = in .nextInt();
        b = in .nextInt();
        c = in .nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter co-ordinates of warehouses");
        for (int i = 0; i < nWare; i++) {
            Warehousesx[i] = in .nextInt();
            Warehousesy[i] = in .nextInt();
        }

    }

    void calcMinMax() {
        int min = Warehousesx[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < nWare; i++) {
            if (Warehousesx[i] < min) {
                min = Warehousesx[i];
            }
        }
        minX = min;

        for (int i = 0; i < nWare; i++) {
            if (Warehousesx[i] > maxX) {
                maxX = Warehousesx[i];
            }
        }
    }

    void pointscalc() {
        for (int i = Math.abs(minX); i < Math.abs(maxX); i++) {
            int min = minX;
            Pointsx[i] = min;
            Pointsy[i] = (-a * i - c) / b;
            min++;
        }
        for (int j = Math.abs(minX); j < Math.abs(maxX); j++) {
            double sumDist = 0;

            x2 = Pointsx[j];
            y2 = Pointsy[j];

            for (int i = 0; i < nWare; i++) {
                x1 = Warehousesx[i];
                y1 = Warehousesy[i];

                distance[j] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
                sumDist = distance[j] + sumDist;
            }
            sumDistArr[j] = sumDist;
        }
    }

    void distanceCalc() {
        int a = Math.abs(minX);
        int b = Math.abs(maxX);
        double min = sumDistArr[a];

        for (int i = a + 1; i < b; i++) {
            if (sumDistArr[i] < min) {
                min = sumDistArr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(min);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HighwayFactory nh86 = new HighwayFactory();
        nh86.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: And the runtime error is.. ?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?? Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @UnknownOctopus Actually sir, its nzec , which is Non Zero Exit Code for c its not adding return 0; I am assuming its array out of bounds in java.

Comment: @digidude Im not getting any error on my environment.

Comment: @GauravSharma ... i checked for some possible causes of NZEC on codechef. There could be an issue with the way you provide input. Your program accepts co-ordinates in new lines but they usually provide input separated by spaces ..... could be a cause. Check the last comment on this link ......................   [https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7593/why-do-i-get-an-nzec?page=1#7594](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7593/why-do-i-get-an-nzec?page=1#7594)

Comment: @digidude thanks I will check it out , bdw it doesnt give any error on my computer , just the o/p is screwed.

Comment: @GauravSharma .... it won't give error on your computer because you are inputting values as your program expects. On codechef however, they feed input to your program in their format which might not be compatible to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details on what really is the error. And notice this:

```java
System.out.println("enter a,b,c");

a = in .nextInt();
b = in .nextInt();
c = in .nextInt();
```

You are asking for characters "a, b or c", using

```java
.nextInt()
```

to read characters like "a, b, c" will only give you error. If you intend that the input should be stored as an integer, then use parsing.

Also, try using exception handling:

```java
try {
   ....
} catch (Exception e){
    ....
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there: "`try` using exception handling".